# Why I'm not kept logged in when using Passport and sessions? Passport's "isAuthenticated()" always returns false

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, passport.js, passport-local

I am using Angular, Passport and sessions for authentication. I can create a new user, login but,

**Problem**

when checking if the user is logged using Passport's isAuthenticated() function always returns false. I followed the instructions from various online resources and I am unsure if:

**Question**

I can use passport and sessions with my Angular app? or I am just doing something wrong in my code? I would really appreciate it if you guys have any idea/hint why it's not working. Thank you.

**Backend code**

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const seedDB = require("./helpers/dbseed");

const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");

// the model with Passport-Local Mongoose plugged in
const User = require("./models/user");
const Profile = require("./models/profile");
const Recipe = require('./models/recipe');
const Macro = require ("./models/macro");
const Micro = require ("./models/micro");
const Ingredient = require("./models/ingredient");

// const {isLoggedIn} = require("./middleware/auth");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/foodAppCopy', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Mongo Connection open");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("No, Mongo -> Connection Error " + error);
    })

seedDB();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(express.json());

const sessionConfig = {
    secret: 'pass',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    }
}
app.use(session(sessionConfig));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// Create New User
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {name, email, password} = req.body;
        const user = new User({name, email});
        const registeredUser = await User.register(user, password);
        // This is used to create a profile
        res.send(registeredUser._id);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});

// Login
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/recipes'}), 
    async(req, res) => {
});

// Create Profile
app.post('/profile', async(req, res) => {
    const {userID, profileData} = req.body;
    let user = await User.findOne({_id: userID});
    if (user === null || user.length <= 0) {
        return res.status(422).json("Could not create profile");
    } else {
        let newProfile = new Profile({
            userID: user._id,
            dob: profileData.dob,
            gender:profileData.gender,
            weightGoal:profileData.weightGoal,
            weeklyLossFrequency:profileData.weeklyLossFrequency,
        })
        await newProfile.save();
    }
});

// INDEX Recipes
app.get('/recipes', async (req, res) => {
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("error");
        return res.status(422).json("You need to be logged in");
    }
    const recipes = await Recipe.find({});
    res.send(recipes);
});
```

**Middleware file**

```
    module.exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
        if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next()
        } 
        res.status(403).send("Please login");
     }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsfG8.png
```

**User Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
    },
})

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
    usernameField: "email"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

**Error in the console**
[image]

Comment: Can you also show the user model file? Because that's where most of the authentication stuff happens obviously.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. I just added it now.

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. I'm looking at this ```app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/recipes', failureRedirect: "/login"}), 
    async(req, res) => {
})``` and I can see that the async function doesn't finish.

Comment: Also your user schema is wrong, you only have email added, you need password as well. There are a lot of issues with your code. Can you show me the link to the example/tutorial you were looking?


I suspect it's because you're not setting the bearer token anywhere or something with your user registration is totally wrong.

Comment: Hi @ZombieChowder! Yes, I'm new to the backend and I'm following a youtube tutorial and this is how the login is left. Not sure exactly what should be in there. Also, I updated my code with more details. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: It's an Udemy course. He doesn't mention anything regarding bearer token. I can move the conversation in a chat and I can share the code he has in the course if you would like

Comment: he just uses passport and sessions and his model doesn't have a password as well

Comment: it's this one https://github.com/Colt/YelpCamp/tree/291b1146dfd2e0449b90aed6c3b20cdeda8a0485

Comment: I'm looking at the example but it's difficult to compare it to your code since you've shared only a part of it. Feel free to move us to a chat if you haven't solved your problem yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing what's wrong because you didn't precise the port of your application in your question, but I assume it's 4200 as I see that you have added these lines to the original project:

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

And you probably added them after having experienced this kind of error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

If my assumptions are right, then the problem you have is another problem related to  your backend running on the port 3000 and the frontend running on the port 4200.

Indeed, you are using the session and you have configured it to use cookies. However, cookies won't be sent from another domain (different port is considered different domain) unless some special options are set:

- The [`access-control-allow-credentials: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) header in the HTTP response
- The [`withCredentials`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#withCredentials) option in the HTTP request
- The [`SameSite=none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#none) cookie attribute

These options tend to lower the security level of your website (other CORS options do as well). The easiest solution to stay at a good security level and avoid those errors is to serve the frontend and the backend on the same port.

On the local environment, this can be done with the [Angular development proxy](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server) which you could configure like this:

```
{
  "/backend": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/backend": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget the reference to that new file in the `angular.json` file:

```
"proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
```

After that, change all of your backend calls from `http://localhost:3000/...` to `http://localhost:4200/backend/...` and your login should work fine (you can remove the two CORS lines as well).

Comment: Wow, yes, you are right! Also, I did all the changes you recommended and per doc, in my angular.json I added options like this      "options": {
            "browserTarget": "food-app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          }. However, now I get these errors in my console when I first sign up & login message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/recipes: 404"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
status: 404
url: "http://localhost:4200/recipes"
and terminal [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /profile from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:3000

Comment: You forgot a detail in the last step: don't call `/recipes` but `/backend/recipes`

Comment: understood. Maybe I don't understand correctly, but I replaced every backend call in Angular. Eg: recipes service: public fetchRecipes() {
    return this.http
      .get<Recipe[]>("http://localhost:4200/backend/recipes", {})
      .pipe(
        map((responseData) => {
          let receivedDbRecipes: Recipe[] = [];
          responseData.map((eachDbRecipe) => {
            receivedDbRecipes.push(eachDbRecipe);
          });
          return receivedDbRecipes;
        }),
        catchError((errorResponse) => {
          return throwError(errorResponse);
        })
      );
  }

Comment: Yes that's it, you could even write relative URLs without specifying the hostname and port: `/backend/recipes`. That doesn't work?

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, not sure how you figured it out with so little info :)). Now it's working. Never in gazillion years, I would think that was the problem. Thank you for taking the time to explain, I really appreciate it as I learned a lot from you. However, I have just this thing left to ask: I'm getting this error in my terminal and I'm not sure why HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /profile from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:3000 (ECONNRESET). (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors). Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: To be honest I don't get how it works if you have these error messages saying that the frontend proxy didn't reach the backend. The `/login` URL works but not `/profile`?

Comment: apologise for my late reply. When I first sign-up I get a 422 error "Failure response for http://localhost:4200/backend/recipes and redirects me to login (in db creates both user and profile) and if I login with the newly created details it works and then when I refresh the page I get those errors in the terminal

Comment: and after a couple of minutes, I get in the console: "HttpErrorResponse"
status: 504
statusText: "Gateway Timeout"
url: "http://localhost:4200/backend/profile" and that error in the terminal

Comment: I guess the 504 error is related to the `/profile` handler that doesn't send a response with the `res` object in case of success, so the HTTP request just hangs and times out. You should send a 200 code with an empty body at least.

Comment: Understood. Apologise for the lengthy exchange of messages. I have just 1 more, and that's it. When I create the profile it doesn't redirect to /recipes but to /login and I get the 422 Unprocessable Entity error for /recipes. I was thinking that when I register it will log me in and I would be able to see /recipes directly without logging in afterwards. Am I doing something wrong or why is this not the behaviour I get? when I check on tutorials after registration it's behaving like the user is logged in immediately after registering. Sorry and thank you!

Comment: You forgot to use [`req.login`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/) after the profile creation. It is also in the initial code you're working on: https://github.com/Colt/YelpCamp/blob/291b1146dfd2e0449b90aed6c3b20cdeda8a0485/routes/users.js#L16